# Neo4j Cypher Merge query isolation level

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I came across this Gist http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?8012859 the other day and thought it would be handy for generating orderIds across a HA cluster. I have created a simple implementation and my unit tests are failing because the count field is not providing unique values in a thread safe manner.

There is a comment by Andres Taylor in the [2.0 version of the documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0/query-merge.html) which reads

> We will be working more on isolation in 2.0. This problem should be fixed before the final release.

I am using Neo4J embedded 2.1.3, Neo HA and Spring Data Neo4J 3.1.4 and whilst I cannot find anything explicit in the release notes the `Provisional Feature` warning has been removed.

I believe that the CREATE part of the MATCH query is happening in isolation but I believe that the ON MATCH part is operating on stale data, acquiring a write lock to the single unique node but not re-reading data after waiting for the acquisition. Looking at the [transaction documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions.html) it looks like the default isolation is READ COMMITTED, because of the nature of the my Merge query (combined Read/Write semantics - `nid.count = nid.count + 1`) should I be manually acquiring an exclusive lock before performing the operation?

Code snippets:
**The Node:**

```
@NodeEntity
public class UniqueId {

  @GraphId
  private Long id;

  @Indexed(indexType=IndexType.LABEL, unique=true)
  private String type;

  private long count;

  //getters/setters/stuff
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public interface UniqueIdRepository extends GraphRepository<UniqueId> {

  @Query(value = "MERGE (nid:UniqueId{type:{0}}) " +
                 "ON CREATE SET nid:_UniqueId, nid.count = 1 " +
                 "ON MATCH SET nid.count = nid.count + 1 " +
                 "RETURN nid.count")
  public long generateUid(String type);
}
```

**Service Method:**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Long generateOrderId() {
    return idRepository.generateUid("Order");
}
```

**Simple Unit Test:**

```
@Test
public void testLots() throws Exception {       
    final Map<Long, Object> ids = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    Thread t1 = new GenerateRunnable(200, ids);
    Thread t2 = new GenerateRunnable(200, ids);
    Thread t3 = new GenerateRunnable(200, ids);
    Thread t4 = new GenerateRunnable(200, ids);
    Thread t5 = new GenerateRunnable(200, ids);

    //Run method now just contains...
    // for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
    //      Long uid = idService.generateOrderId();
    //      objects.put(uid, PRESENT);
    //      System.out.println(uid);
    //  }

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    t5.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
    t5.join();

    assertThat(ids.size(), equalTo(1000));
}
```

Whilst he run method is using the service at the minute, I have also called directly to the repository, run the query using the SDN neo4j template and directly using the ExecutionEngine - in the later cases manually creating and committing the transactions.

I did start a [conversation in the Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/rNgN_2ldXWk) where Michael kindly helped me with a mistake in the query semantics, but I have brought the conversation over here as I believe that there is an error in my code, or my understanding rather then an issue with Neo4J itself.

If I could read Scala properly I may have stood a better chance of working this through myself, so I'll put that on my learning list, however I note that when debugging I enter a wait state in TransactionBoundQueryContext$NodeOperations.setProperty (by this point having passed through the findNodes component of MergeNodeAction acquiring and releasing locks as it goes and now processing the `onMatch.foreach(...)` code MergeNodeAction:86)

I have other mechanisms for generating this value, but this looked like a very neat solution, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I do not know if this is a bug, or whether I am using MERGE in a way that it wasn't intended, possibly my question was long and rambling and put those who know better off.. Anyway, I've ended up manually locking the node that I want to maintain control over:

```
Transaction tx = template.getGraphDatabase().beginTx();

try {
    tx.acquireWriteLock(lockNode);
    long id = idRepository.generateUid(TYPE_ORDER);
    tx.success();
    return id;
}
finally {
    tx.close();
}
```

Where `generateUid` is the same query as in the original question. Of course I am assuming responsibility for the access and update of the value rather than deferring that to the database engine but I am generating unique incremental ids this way.